# Storing multiple values with same key in HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap

I had an interview today and my interviewer asked me that how can I store multiple values having the same key in HashMap?
She gave me this example-->If I am given a list of String and I am suppose to store the length of String as key and the String itself as value.

I gave her the following solution in how I will be using HashMap:

```
Map<Integer, ArrayList<String>> map = new HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<String>>();
```

Integer being the length of the String and the ArrayList will store the Strings of that particular length.

The interviewer said that this is one way of using the HashMap but there is another way in which I won't be requiring ArrayList or any other data structure. During interview, I couldn't come up with any solution and now after enough googling, I still have nothing. Can anyone tell me how can I achieve the solution to this question?

Thanks!

Comment: `HashMap` by definition has one value per key... Not quite sure what the interviewer was getting at.

Comment: @user3580294: that's what I told her.. but she told me that there lies a very basic conceptual answer to this..

Comment: what are you allowed to use ? Is she talking about hashmap datastructure of concept ?

Comment: @Amir: just a simple HashMap..

Comment: Well, considering the [Map javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) says "A map cannot contain duplicate keys; each key can map to at most one value.", I think the interviewer was off his/her rocker. Edit: Or maybe just looking for a useless solution

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way without using ANY DATA STRUCTURE is concatenating all strings in values.

For e.g.

```
map.put(2,"rr*tt*yy");
map.put(3,"nnn*ggg*sss");
map.put(4,"ffff*dddd*jjjj");
```

Comment: Well, that's an interesting thought. Absolutely useless in the real world, but certainly a possibility...

Comment: Well Well Well... I guess there's the possible answer to her question... Thanks for the answer mate :)

Comment: +1 Interesting. That could be what the interviewer going for. Though I'd say that still counts as a data structure, just undocumented and not using the language's own facilities: it's essentially implementing an ArrayList-style list using either a delimiter or known element length. (You don't need the "*" between substrings because their length is known from the key. And you'd need to use an escaping technique if using a delimiter.)

Comment: And I wouldn't say it's useless in the real world: fixed-length records are common in some older software. And result set buffers for some SQL drivers work this way: the data for multiple rows of a CHAR column are just packed in to one big char array, with each string being the length of the max length of that column.

Comment: Though I want to emphasize that I think these all count as data structures, and the asker's bewilderment is totally understandable and IMHO technically correct. If the interviewer had asked "without any other *classes*", that would make more sense.

Comment: @AndrewJanke Well, I learned something new today. Thanks! I assumed that maps would be constructed in a more "sensible" way, but evidently I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

May be the interviewer was looking to check if you know the 3rd party APIs or not.
There are multiple APIs available to do this.
Some of them can be found at
http://java.dzone.com/articles/hashmap-%E2%80%93-single-key-and

Comment: The interviewer says wont need any other data structure, implying no 3rd party apis

Answer (score 0):

One option is every time you want to insert a record into the map, get the length of the String, salt then encrypt the size of the String to use as the key. BAM: you have a (fairly) unique retrievable key for each String without having to much around with String concatenation.

Just make sure you use a reversible encryption algorithm.

Another option would be to generate out a UUID and concatenate the size of the string to that.

```
UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID()
String key = stringSize + "," + uuid;
```

This will also result in a unique value that you can retrieve later using String.split();